# Binding a contextMenu to dynamic DOM content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery contenxt menu plugin from here: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/index.php

Using the menu looks pretty simple, and is achieved as follows

```
$(function() {
  $('#staticContent').contextMenu(menu1, { theme:'vista' });
});

var menu1 = [
  {'Option 1':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 1!"); } },
  $.contextMenu.separator,
  {'Option 2':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 2!"); } }
];
```

This works fine. It doesn't work when the content is dynamic. Can someone show how to achieve this when the content is dynamic please.

I've tried this and variants of it but to no avail..

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#dynamicContent', function(e) {
   e.toElement.contextMenu('#contextMenuToolbar', { theme: 'vista' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate#entry-longdesc) check the example.

```
$(document.body).delegate('click', '#dynamicContent', function(e) {
   e.toElement.contextMenu('#contextMenuToolbar', { theme: 'vista' });
});
```